# Typescript dynamically infer type

Tags: typescript, inferred-type

I have some function stored in a variable, and want to pass it to another function, and i want this function will reuse it's parameters. But it doesn't work. See the examples

```
// I want pass this function (and steal its parameters dynamically)
const a = (a: string) => { }

const b = (...args: Parameters<typeof a>) {
}

const c = (c) => (...args: Parameters<typeof c>) => {
}

const d = <T>(...args: Parameters<T>) => {
}

// this works:
b()

// this doesn't work, need to make it working
// it doesn't work because for TS is c literally ANY here (c) => (...args: Parameters<typeof c>) => {}
c(a)()

// this works but i don't was this solution becuase would be ugly and long
d<typeof a>(1)

// in real world the last solution would look like
Foo.make<typeof Some.Function.GetIt>(Some.Function.GetIt, ...)
```

Comment: What does your function return? I don't see where you are passing the parameters back out? You should show a working examples, not one that is missing details

Comment: doesnt matter what it returns, now it is about capturing it's type dynamically and it doesn't work in the case "C"

Comment: it needs to capture it and pass it back to the caller?

Comment: i need to steal the parameters and reuse it on another class method to call the passed function

Comment: It would definitely help for this example code to constitute a [mcve] instead of invalid syntax and mismatching types (is the parameter supposed to be `string` or `number` or missing?).  For all I know [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDAFHAXDaAnAlmAcwEokA+GAbxgF8AoUSWAIyVQDoO5sCJMAFLnAC2AUygjsEADxQAngAcRIAGbxSJROSp0mKAER6i9cNBjBWUgIIwRAD3FgAJhHhhZAbQC6pFMEwoONi4eTEsNcjg3cPZObl4YMLJKGno0In1DAG5jRhhHCwAVG3sRJxcAzkxI2Wjqn0Dg+IFsYTEJaQL1JO1aRxkFJVU4HwMjWnHxoA) answers your question but I can't tell from the example code.

Comment: `b() // this works` doesn't actually work. Can you post an example that compiles in [the playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play)?

Comment: @AaronBeall b() and d() works http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDAFHAXDaAnAlmAcwEokA+GAbxgF8AoW0SWAIyVQDpO5sCJMAFbnAC2AUyijsEADxQAngAdRIAGbxSJCrToNw0GMDYoAHiUTkUndt14ChYiVNmLla4xrKVt9RvoAmbNIAKqSWXDx8MILYIuKSMiFm5Fo6APSpMADuINgA1ny0zChE9OkwfiCiEGCw2XkMaEQoAIwltGUVNVlwXVAAFrgQWCAANgCuULjgtH7OSqrqLURAA

Comment: @luky In that link I get 5 errors including, on `b()`: `Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.` -- please fix your example so it compiles and we can help you

Comment: @AaronBeall that is expected behaviour because function a has one parameter of type string. you can write any string there. you can work with the left window no need to compile i guess.

Comment: @luky The point is your example doesn't work. Jcalz said it right, we don't know exactly what you want because your example is incomplete and doesn't compile.

Comment: @AaronBeall the example works fine. it is capturing the arguments of passed variable a to other functions, so function b() requires one argument of string type, d()() as well, c doesn't. i need to pass the function as argument and get it's parameters but c() doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work out for you:

```
const a = (a: string) => { }

const c = <F extends (...args: any) => any>(c: F) => (...args: Parameters<F>) => {
}

// c(a) is inferred to (a: string) => void
c(a)("test");
```

Comment: Hi, yes just now someone replied also this solution on TS forum, thank you very much it works :)